# How to remove punctuation from a string

Tags: python

One of the project that I've been working on is to create a word counter, and to do that, I have to effectively remove all punctuation from a string.

I have tried using the split method and split at punctuation, however, this will later make the list very weird (from separating at a word to having a list that has 5 words). I then tried to have a list or a string full of punctuation, and use a for loop to eliminate all punctuation, but both are not successful

```
content_string = "This, is a test! to see: whether? or not. the code can eliminate punctuation"
punctuation = list["'", '"', ',', '.', '?', '!', ':', ';', '()']
for i in content_string.lower():
    if i in punctuation:
        i = i.replace[i," "]
    else:
        i = i
```

It says that

> "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable"

This message appears both when using a string or using a list.

Comment: Try changing your brackets in `replace` with parenthesis.

Comment: Your error comes from a syntax error in line 2. Check my answer for a solution and an efficient way to remove the punctution from your string

Answer (score 1):

There is a mix with parenthesis versus square brackets.
`list` and `replace` are functions, arguments are passed with parenthesis.

Also, try to describe your algorithm with words:
example:

For all forbidden characters, i want to remove them from my content (replace with space)

Here is an implementation you can start with:

```
content_string = "This, is a test! to see: whether? or not. the code can eliminate punctuation"
punctuation = ["'", '"', ',', '.', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')']
for i in punctuation:
    content_string = content_string.replace(i, " ")
```

Comment: This is the most straightforward solution I would recommend for beginners.

Comment: But it's quite inefficient if your string is very large.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Inefficient? Compared to what ?
This simple clear solution with a million time the content: tested at 595 ms
The solution you suggest (the `''.join` solution), same content: 17886 ms. 30 times slower...

Answer (score 0):

To create a list, you use `l = [...]` not `l = list[...]`, and functions/methods (such as `str.replace`) are called with parenthesis, not square brackets, however, you can use `re.sub` to do this in a much better and simpler way:

```
content_string = "This, is a test! to see: whether? or not. the code can eliminate punctuation"

punctuation = ["'", '"', ',', '.', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')'] # '(', ')' not `()`

import re

new_string = re.sub('|'.join(map(re.escape, punctuation)), '', content_string)

print(new_string)
```

Output:

```
This is a test to see whether or not the code can eliminate punctuation
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error

```
"TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable"
```

comes from the line

```
punctuation = list["'", '"', ',', '.', '?', '!', ':', ';', '()']
```

To define a list you either use brackets [ ] without the keyword list, or if you use list you have to put parenthesis (although in this case converting a list into a list is redundant)

```
# both options will work, but the second one is redundant and therefore wrong
punctuation = ["'", '"', ',', '.', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')']
punctuation = list(["'", '"', ',', '.', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')'])
```

Notice that the last element `()` must be splitted in two elements `(` and `)`

Now to achieve what you want in an efficient way, use a conditional comprehension list

```
''.join([i if i not in punctuation else ' ' for i in content_string])
```

result:

```
'This  is a test  to see  whether  or not  the code can eliminate punctuation'
```

Notice that according to your code, you are not **removing** the punctuation symbols but replacing them for spaces.

Comment: Your list comprehension is pretty slow. If you really want efficient, use `string.translate`. For deleting a set of characters, this method in my experience is by far the fastest.

Comment: I just timed it: straight `replace` is 2.64 µs, `str.translate` is 1.73 µs, and `''.join` with a list comprehension is 29.7 µs. Making `punctuation` a set improves your method to 8.14 µs. In practical application, there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple bugs in the code.

**First one:**

The `list` keyword is obsolete. 
If you wanted to use it, you would need to add parentheses `()` so that the call would be properly done on the items in the already defined list.

BAD `punctuation = list["'", '"', ',', '.', '?', '!', ':', ';', '()']`

BETTER `punctuation = list(["'", '"', ',', '.', '?', '!', ':', ';', '()'])`

But simply defining the list with regular `[]` syntax would be enough, and also more efficient than a `list()` call.

**Second one:**

You will not be able to replace parentheses with the `if i in punctuation:` check.
This is because they are a two character long string, and you are iterating over single characters of your string. So you will always compare `'('` or `')'` with `'()'`.

A possible fix - add parentheses separately to the punctuation list as single characters.

**Third** bug, or rather an obsolete else instruction:

```
    else:
        i = i
```

This servers no purpose whatsoever, you should skip the `else` instruction.

**Fourth**, the most apparent bug:

In your for loop you are editing `i` variable which is a copy of a single character from the string that you are iterating over. You should perform the change on the original string, this could be done with the usage of `enumerate` - only if you first turned your string into a list, so that you could modify its values.

```
for i, char in enumerate(list(content_string.lower())):
    if char in punctuation:
        content_string[i] = ' '
```

---

Anyway, the goal you are trying to achieve can come down to a one-liner, using a list comprehension and a string join on the resulting list afterwards:

`content_string = ''.join([char if char not in punctuation else ' ' for char in content_string.lower()])`

Comment: Strings are immutable, so `content_string[i] = ' '` won't work.

Comment: Right, my bad. This could be possible if you called list() on your string, and then joined the elements back into a string.